# How to use pm2 to start node app?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm new to node.js and want to deploy an app on the serve. currently the app runs when run `node start`.

I'm wondering how can I make it to run like an upstart process using `pm2`.

In tutorials that I've seen pm2 is used to run a file like `index.js`. but when I use `pm2 node start` the app process does not start
Appreciate your help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [pm2/docs/usage/quick-start](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/).
The easiest way is like this:

```
pm2 start index.js
```